# paypal parameater to create recurring profile is giving error can one please help me out

Tags: php, rest, paypal, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing

I am using curl to get token_id to create paypal recurring profile 
normally it worked several time but it giving an error with this params

```
Array
(
    [user] => shamim_api1.xxxxxxxx.com
    [pwd] => UK8XH8T5H6RSQELU
    [signature] => AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AQIeUAbp6QyKOeJ.4B1pPA-HfVSD
    [AMT] => 1.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [returnUrl] => http://xxx.xxdemo.com/xxup/php/payment/process_recuring
    [cancelUrl] => http://xxx.xxdemo.com/xxup/php/payment/cancelled
    [notifyURL] => http://xxx.xxdemo.com/xxup/php/payment/notify
    [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2015-06-22 14:43:04
    [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
    [BILLINGTYPE] => RecurringPayments
    [BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION] => Recuring payment of 1.00 per 1 Day for 12 months 
    [DESC] => Recuring payment of 1.00 per 1 Day for 12 months
    [BILLINGPERIOD] => Day
    [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0
    [MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS] => 1
    [custom] => SUB_R_136
    [AUTOBILLOUTAMT] => 1.00
    [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1
    [TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 365
    [VERSION] => 86.0
    [NOSHIPPING] => 1
)
```

it is giving error :

```
 Array
(
[TIMESTAMP] => 2015-06-22T09:15:15Z
[CORRELATIONID] => eb6b1e9564fbb
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 86
[BUILD] => 17098556
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 11518
[L_ERRORCODE1] => 11516
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid billing period.
[L_SHORTMESSAGE1] => Invalid billing frequency
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Billing period must be one of Day, Week, SemiMonth, or Year
[L_LONGMESSAGE1] => Billing frequency must be > 0 and be less than or equal to one year
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
[L_SEVERITYCODE1] => Error
)
```

i cannot assume the reason as all the param in error thos are as per the error were proper ...
please check an help me out ...

Comment: HI I have changed the "TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES" to "TOTALBILLINGCYCLES"  is their a way that i can get ipn notification each time while an autometed recurring payment is received ??? i mean hare each day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are partially specifying two different billing cycles, TRIAL (free) and regular (paying).

Since your description suggests you do not intend to have a trial period (of one year) but rather actually intend to bill daily for a year, change TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES to TOTALBILLINGCYCLES. This will give you all three required parameters (period type, number of days in a cycle, and number of cycles) to define the paying period, and none of these three parameters for a trial period (so there will be no trial period).